# For the existence of one-point compactification, do we need locally compactness?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms, compactification

In the book *Topology* by Munkres, at page 184, it is given the existence and uniqueness of one point compactification of a locally compact Hausdorff space; however, in the existence part, I can't see where we needed the locally compactness of that space, and this raised the question:

Does one point compactification of a Hausdorff space always exist (even though it is not unique) ?

See the proof in the book;

(sorry for the images; they are just for reference for those that doesn't have the book with them)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you remove a point from a compact Hausdorff space, you get a locally compact space.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Nice observation; thanks for sharing, but I'm much more interested in the other way looking at the situation: If I have a Hausdorff space, can I always find a compact Hausdorff space by just adding a single point to my original space ?

Comment: If $X$ is Hausdorff but not locally compact its one point compactification won't be Hausdorff, but it can be constructed in the same way

Comment: For **every** space there is the [one-point-Alexandrov compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(mathematics)#Alexandroff_one-point_compactification).

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti This suggest the hypothesis that $X$ is locally compact is used in the existence of compact & **Hausdorff** one-point compactification of $X$, but where is it exactly ?

Comment: "we can choose a compact set in $X$..." last paragraph

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @drhab I don't think one point compactification works on an already compact space (but then there is no need for compactification though)

Comment: For the rest, I agree that in general you don't need locally compactness for the compactification (but it is necessary if we want that the compactification is Hausdorff if I remember correctly)

Comment: @Math_QED If $X$ is a compact space then so is $X\cup\{c\}$ where $c\notin X$ is an isolated point. So also in that case there is an Alexandrov compactification. My comment only concerned the title of this question.

Comment: I agree, but can we call it an Alexandrov compactification (as in OP's construction). How would you show that the extra point is isolated in this construction?

Comment: @Math_QED if $X$ is already compact then you still get a compact space, but $X$ isn't dense in it

Comment: Yeah embedding X densely in the origial space was in my definition. Thanks for the clarification both. Seems like it's a matter of definitions.

Comment: A compact Hausdorff space is normal ($T_4$) and hence is completely regular ( $T_{3\frac {1}{2}})$ by Urysohn's Lemma, and regular ($T_3$). Regular and completely regular are hereditary properties: Any sub-space  of a regular (or completely regular) space is also regular (or completely regular).... So if a compact Hausdorff space $Y$ is a compactification of $X$ then $X$ must be completely regular.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet What do you mean by "hereditary propert" ?

Comment: In topology a property P is called hereditary when  ($X\subset Y$ and $Y$ has property P$)\implies (X $ has property P).

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any space $X$ we can construct a space $\alpha(X)$, the Aleksandrov extension of $X$ by defining a space $Y$ as Munkres does with the extra provision that we take all complements of **closed** compact subsets of $X$ as the extra neighbourhoods for $\infty$. One can easily check that $\alpha(X)$ is then compact.

The "closed" is needed in general because if e.g. $X$ is not Hausdorff it could have some compact subset $K$ which is not closed, and then (if we were to omit the closed condition) $(X\setminus K) \cup \{\infty\}$ would be open while its intersection with $X$ would be $X\setminus K$, which was not open, so if we left out the closed condition $X$ would not have the same topology as a subspace of $\alpha(X)$ as originally, going against the idea of an extension/compactification: we want to *embed* $X$ in a larger space with better properties, so in the larger space it should be a subspace with the same topology that it had originally.

If we want $Y = \alpha(X)$ to be Hausdorff, (so in particular $X$ should then be Hausdorff, as a subspace of $Y$) we need to be able to separate $\infty$ from every point $x$ in $X$. As a neighbourhood of $\infty$ is of the form $\{\infty\} \cup X \setminus C$, with $C$ compact and closed, every point $x$ should then have a neighbourhood that sits inside a compact closed set, i.e. $X$ must be locally compact.

So $\alpha(X)$ can always be defined such that $\alpha(X)\setminus X$ is a point and $X$ is a subspace of $\alpha(X)$ and it is always compact (regardless of $X$) but $\alpha(X)$ is Hausdorff iff $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff. A special case is when $X$ is already Hausdorff and compact, in which case we add an isolated point $\infty$ (as $X$ can be taken as $C$, a compact closed subset) and we get that $X$ is not dense in $\alpha(X)$.

Normally we only consider Hausdorff compactifications and in that case the local compactness is needed for the Hausdorffness of the construction $\alpha(X)$. And also because then $X$ is an open subset of a compact Hausdorff space and thus locally compact for that reason.